# How can I get 1-10MB/s of debugging data to and from a dev board?

Tags: usb, serial

Here's the fundamental problem I have: I'm looking at a dev board for, say, a TI/AD/Microchip microprocessor or DSP. This is long before a full product design; we're talking proof-of-concept work here. I want to send data from a PC to be processed by my firmware, or have my firmware send data to my PC. And I want the rate to be of the order of 1-10MB/s.

15+ years ago, 1-10MB/s would have been quite niche. kB/s would have been more usual, and the dev board would have had a DB9 connector on it. I could have just plugged a serial cable between the dev board and my PC, perhaps with a USB-to-serial converter, and read and write to `COMX` or `/dev/ttySX`.

However, this scheme has a number of limitations that are now starting to show up:

- I want MB/s, not kB/s.
- The absolute max UART rate a 100MHz device could manage is still only 0.7 MB/s. SPI on the other hand allows up to 3-4 MB/s.
- It's incredibly rare for PCs to come with serial ports now, so specialised adaptors are needed to interface with a PC eg. USB to serial cable.

But I'm stumped for what I could use to replace the old serial scheme. The main context for this question is sending serialised debugging data between vendor dev boards and a PC before design is finalised, so anything requiring secondary devices eg. Bluetooth isn't super useful. The µPs I typically work with are in the realm of TI's MSP430, Microchip's PIC32M*, and low power DSPs like the TI C55x or C674. Their dev boards might typically come with headers connected to SPI/I2C/UART peripherals.

Ethernet would require full implementation of a networking stack, which isn't really practical on the constrained DSPs or µPs I often work with. Furthermore most PCs only have one ethernet port, if at all, so you wouldn't be able to use it for wired networking.

Ground-up USB requires getting a vendor ID from a 3rd party, and reinventing all sorts of wheels at the driver and software level just to get data from one device to another.

Ideally I'd like to just be able to dump bytes in a peripheral register on my µP and drain it using Python on the PC or vice versa, using a cable most IT departments would have lying around, and get 1-10 MB/s. A bonus would be not having to poll every available port of whatever kind to find the device on a PC. Is this possible?

Comment: Is this for: development debugging, or field diagnostics by a programmer, or field diagnostic by a technician with limited training?

Comment: @NickAlexeev Let's say development debugging. I'm looking for something that's easy to do on a "typical" dev board; field diagnostics would involve the final product where we could eg. design in a high speed FTDI chip connected via I2C. Make sense?

Comment: Serial to USB are cheap and common with many available comm drivers. What better universal host solution do you need ? The FT602 is a FIFO interface to SuperSpeed USB (USB 3.1 Gen 1) USB Video Class (UVC) bridge chip

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Ideally I want something where I don't have to design a separate PCB and get it manufactured. All the FTDI USB-to-header cables I could find use the FT234XD, which only goes up to 3 Mbaud or ~3-400kB/s.

Comment: Precisely what *peripheral* do you find that is shared between MSP430 (which I use a lot), M4k (PIC32) which I also enjoy, and the TI C55x (which I've used and *hated* [especially after dealing with TI support to track down undoc'd behavior] and therefore much MUCH preferring the ADSP-21xx)??? Keep in mind you are asking to just "dump bytes" to a register here. The difference between an MSP430 and an PIC32 is enormous. What do you feel is a common denominator here? How would you actually operate your code on a PIC32 and an MSP430 that would be anything similar?

Comment: @jonk Both have I2C and SPI pins exposed via headers on the dev board. If there were eg. a cable or attachment with breakout connectors (like these [FTDI cables have](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/Cables/USBMPSSE.htm)) that just converted I2C to a serial-over-USB at a high baud rate I'd be set I think.

Comment: FT260 1.2k to 12Mbd UART

Comment: @jonk In case it wasn't clear, I'm not asking for the ability to use common code, but something similar in implementation complexity to using UART peripherals.

Comment: (Incidentially, those [FTDI cables](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/Cables/USBMPSSE.htm) seem like they might actually do the trick, except I've been trying for the last two hours to find proper documentation for them to no avail.)

Comment: Why would you not just use an Arduino with a I2C or SPI sketch to convert to the upstream USB/Serial?

Comment: @JackCreasey I haven't used an Arduino before but I'll look into that, it could be a good way to go.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 That's a nice chip but again, time spent designing and building a second device is time away from the actual project.

Comment: @jonk Thanks for the pointer to the ADSP-21xx, that looks like a really nice device. Are you doing low power stuff with it?

Comment: what's wrong with buying a USB2 or USB3 adapter?

Comment: @detly Also see: http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/ft245r09.pdf (looks interesting, at least.)

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 What kind of adapter though? USB* to a DB9 connecter is a bit useless. I've been looking for a USB* to single wire connectors, but most of them use slower chips or require older OSs.

Comment: many standards exist and are included in low cost uC cards. define specs  for  BW, latency, distance and cost are necessary,

Comment: @detly Regarding the ADSP-21xx, it was replaced by the BlackFin (mostly.) Not sure what's available in the ADSP-21xx line now. I started with the ADSP-2111, went to the ADSP-2105 (for cheap), and then went to the ADSP-218x group. I date back to 1990-1995. Have a look at: http://www.analog.com/en/products/processors-dsp/adsp-21xx-processors.html

Comment: @detly It is incredible for the day. I could do a 1024-pt, complex FP input, complex FP output FFT in 3ms on their cheapest and slowest ADSP-2105! And there's no floating point in the device. Just that I can read two separate data words and do an ALU op in one clock, plus read code. Or do a data read and a data write and an ALU op in one clock. The ALU op can be a fully combinatorial barrel shift, with the ability to auto-find the highest order bit and count the shifts... in one clock... while doing the reads and writes, too. Plus, I never found a single deviation from docs. Not once.

Comment: @detly I did, however, quickly find errors in a batch of DSP chips they sent, right after they shifted to a different FAB. Reported the problem, they asked for my code that checked their CPUs, I gave it to them, and they respun the chips and had new devices to us that worked fine in less than 3 weeks. Wonderful support. Looks like they claim pretty low operational current on that web site. I haven't used their newer devices and didn't need low power at the time, so I can't speak well to their low power operation, today.

Comment: @jonk Tricky to compare with TI, because TI quote mW/Hz and AD quote mW/MIP, but shouldn't be too hard to do the math. My only experience with AD has been their ADC/DACs, which are usually excellent.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 BW needs to be 1-10MB/s, latency... well, <10ms would be nice, but it's not a huge deal. Cost, since I just need a couple of devices for during development, anything $100 USD/AUD or below really.

Comment: MAX3421E  $4
USB Peripheral/Host Controller with SPI Interface  or Arduino shield $26  https://store.arduino.cc/usa/arduino-usb-host-shield

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 They're all great devices but... this is precisely why I'm frustrated. These all involve a great deal more work than just connecting a couple of devices, which is why RS232 stuck around for so long. I'm genuinely surprised that either (a) everyone reinvents the same I2C to USB conversion circuitry and cabling every single time they need >0.5MB/s or (b) no one else needs it.

Comment: Thanks for your comments everyone, I've tried to make the use case more specific without defeating the point of the question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is now entirely different than what was originally posted invalidating all of the community effort in generating responses.

Comment: @ChrisStratton In what way is it entirely different? Most of the text is the same, I simply added some context at the start, most of which was clarified from the comments.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Are you saying a question about data transfer protocols to and from a microprocessor dev board is off topic for an electronics Q&A site? If so, where should I ask?

Comment: I've come to agree that this isn't a useful question, and certainly hasn't generated specific answers. I think it should be deleted but lack the ability to do, so I've flagged it as OT for being too vague.

Answer (score 2):

Modern successor for a RS232 communication port is supposed to be USB. However, people need to realize that if it is used for debug purposes, it must have some serious architecture support at system level, the port must have some internal bridges to uP registers and memories.

Starting in 2002, Intel has made an attempt to implement mandatory [debug functions](http://composter.com.ua/documents/USB-2.0-Debug-Port(John-Keys).pdf) into open-standard EHCI controller. There was even [some support for it](https://www.coreboot.org/EHCI_Debug_Port), from [Linux](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=5c05917e7fe313a187ad6ebb94c1c6cf42862a0b) and Microsoft side, although, as I understand, all the effort had limited success.

With an advent of USB 3, the effort was resurrected, see [USB 3.1 Debug Class Specifications](http://composter.com.ua/documents/USB_Debug_Class.pdf).

Most recent Type-C connector also defines "[Debug Accessory Mode](http://www.usb.org/developers/presentations/USB_DevDays_Hong_Kong_2016_-_USB_Type-C.pdf)", see pp 59-60. I believe there are several auxillary verions in the works on how to use the pins in alternate way, including JTAG functionality.

However, the old RS232 is not going away and refuses to die. The reason is that most uP and mini-OS are relying on venerable COM ports for many functions, and all Linux/Android flavors have a built-in debug support in kernel. And the UART circuitry/port is fairly simple to implement in silicon with very few resources. However, instead of placing bulky DB-9 connectors (which sometimes are bigger than the device itself) people are embedding a UART-USB converter on-board (typically of FTDI type), and use the miniature u-A/B USB connectors to attach to debug host, emulating COM port and using standard terminal software to access it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been clearer with what I meant by "debugging". I wasn't talking about break-and-step level debugging, but higher level serialisation of state and data eg. dumping samples of audio, states of a state machine, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about a UART or serial interface, RS232 is an electrical and pin standard (simply defines what voltage levels a one and a zero are but not the state changes, protocols, speeds, etc).

Not sure where you got the 160000, you can easily go much faster than that with a cheap ftdi part.  As well as fast jtag, swd, spi, i2c, etc with the same part (one with mpsse). (or roll your own protocol).

Depends on what your definition of PC is, desktops are dead, laptops are dying (all being replaced by tablets and phones), the primary PCs remaining are servers and they typically have at least one serial port as that is the primary display interface for booting/debugging, etc.  But I know what you mean.

With the general lack of a need for RS232, usb to uart works just fine for a primary debug from a host/development pc against a target embedded board/system/chip.

For the ones you mentioned you can out run at least some of them with a usb uart solution so the MCU is the bottleneck there.  Of the parts available you are more likely to find ones with uarts than with usb, certainly not ethernet.  Your number one interface is uart, the ftdi parts and probably others make it easy to access any vendor specific or standardized protocols, or wiggle strap pins so you can use the uart to program the part in circuit.  These vary from custom protocols (avr xmega), to stock spi while in reset (avr if I remember right), uart (msp430, a number of other brands/models), jtag, swd for the cortex-ms, all with a simple ftdi breakout board.

uart still dominates as generally having the lightest footprint on the bootloader. ethernet as you pointed out requires a stack, even cheating with UDP, you still need way more code than checking the receive buffer not empty bit and reading an already processed byte out of a uart peripheral.  usb, if the mcu has it may be mostly done in hardware, so there are some that it is a lightweight thing but you often still have to enumerate yourself and respond to the host when requested, possibly more work than a dumbed down udp stack (the ones I have used it is other than the EZ-USB 8051).

You can get up to a MB/s with uart on some devices, but faster than that you are going to have to build a stack usb or ethernet or custom.

Comment: I'm going to address things in separate comments here, hope you don't mind. Good catch on the RS232 thing, I do that a lot because they used to be so synonymous. Fixed in the question.

Comment: The 16kB/s figure was an error, it should have been 0.69 MB/s (for a 100MHz DSP with a min. 16 divisor for UART baud and 8-N-1 protocol).

Comment: Re. FTDI parts - I have used such parts in products before, and I agree they're very useful. But my problem concerns those times when I'm nowhere near that stage yet... when I'm looking at different dev boards, trying to establish proof of concept, etc. I don't really want to spend time designing Yet Another Breakout PCB that'll fall apart before the next project starts! I mean, if I have to, I have to... but if there's a cable or ready-made board, *I want that!*

Comment: Re. the dying PC - sure they're not driving sales like they used to, but I think they're far from dead, especially in the context of development and design. However, even engineers need our laptops, and the trend there is fewer connectors of fewer different types.

Comment: the bus pirate is basically an ftdi breakout board. you dont have to re-design anything, though one breakout board can work for all projects just like a screwdriver move it from one to another.

Comment: you can still buy pcs sure, but there are real concerns, the average user has gone from desktop to laptop and a percentage dont use that anymore they stream movies on their phone rather than stick dvds in a laptop (one of the main drivers for laptop sales for a while outside business). business is heavy on the laptop use light on the desktops.  and that is a big concern for developers of the software and hardware for these tablets and phones, are we expected to use a bluetooth mouse and keyboard on an ipad to do development?  hope not.

Comment: servers though they are cranking those things out although they dont actually resemble servers anymore. various shaped clumps of something that slides into to something, flat or rectangular, often no case, sometimes even no power supply just use a common supply off the rack, will keep evolving...

Comment: pc's, desktop or server, but mostly desktop are dripping with usb, so that is plan A usb to something, one ethernet usually for a desktop/workstation but you can get a switch at walmart or other store down the street and turn that into as many ports as you want.  can make up your own protocol, or cheat on udp (dont arp, do the master slave, swap the mac, swap the ip, small fixed sized packets, you do have to respond to arp.  listen for arp respond, listen for udp, respond, udp doesnt require a checksum dont even have to do that).

Comment: my guess is we will be developing on tablets, with wireless input (keyboard/mouse) and maybe wireless to a larger display before long.  or....raspberry pis.  and those have usb, and a uart...

Comment: The Bus Pirate is a very nifty device! I'll definitely look into that!

Answer (score 0):

If the MCU is a Cortex-M you could look at Segger's J-Trace or J-Link and use it with RTT. RTT is a kind of a terminal-over-JTAG. The MCU places data in a RAM buffer and the debugger polls it. [They advertise a speed of 3 MB/s.](https://www.segger.com/products/debug-probes/j-link/models/model-overview/)